# How to limit generic list stack in Unity3D .Net?

Tags: .net, generics, unity-game-engine, collections, stack

I have a search function that fills empty pixels and generates 8 searches beside every searched pixel recursively to fill voids, using a generic list Stack, attempting to fill true/false values in a 1000^3 voxel. i.e. a billion sized boolean array.

Memory incrases to 10GB and then there is a memory error.

I want to delete the duplicates in the stack, and to find a way to limit it without missing the floodfill checks. If i omit stack entries which should be run/verified, the floodfill will probably fail. How can i de-duplicate the stack?

```
function floodFill( q: Vector3  ) //floodfill algo of 3d bool voxel cubes starting from point q
{   
    if ( q.x < 0 || q.x > bsizex || q.y < 0 || q.y > bsizey || q.z < 0 || q.z > bsizez) return;

    var stack : Stack.<Vector3>  = new Stack.<Vector3>();
    stack.Push(q);
     while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        if ( CountFilledVoxels % 100000== 0 )//display progress readout
        {
            print(CountFilledVoxels+ "   ------     " +
            (Time.realtimeSinceStartup-tt)+" -=-=-== " + stack.Count );
            yield WaitForFixedUpdate(); 
        }

        var p : Vector3= stack.Pop();
        var x = p.x;
        var y = p.y;
        var z = p.z;
        if ( x < 0 || x > bsizex || y < 0 || y > bsizey || z < 0 || z > bsizez) continue;

        if (readBoolArray( x , y , z ) == false)
        {
            WriteBoolArray( x , y , z , true) ;

            stack.Push(new Vector3(x+1,y,z));
            stack.Push(new Vector3(x-1,y,z));
            stack.Push(new Vector3(x,y+1,z));
            stack.Push(new Vector3(x,y-1,z));
            stack.Push(new Vector3(x,y,z+1));
            stack.Push(new Vector3(x,y,z-1));               
        }                         
    }                             
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but your stack represents a 3-dimensional array of vectors, each vector representing it's own coordinates linearly ?

Comment: I wrote a complete solution to this problem here: https://unity3dmc.blogspot.fr/2017/02/ultimate-3d-floodfill-scanline.html